# Disallow all directories including a given word in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, disallow

I would like to disallow all directories including a given phrase, i.e.

- `www.example.com/directory-1-aaa/`
- `www.example.com/directory-1-bbb/`
- `www.example.com/directory-1-ccc/`
- `www.example.com/directory-1-ddd/`
- `www.example.com/directory-1-eee/`

....

- `www.example.com/directory-1-xxx/`

Would following disallow rule include all these cases:

```
Disallow: */directory-1
```

Comment: To clarify, you only want to disallow crawling? These directories should still be accessible?

Comment: Are all these directories in the root of your site?  Or are some of them deeper like `/foo/directory-1-xxx/`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, all major search engines, supports wildcard in robots.txt (an unofficial extension), so Disallow: /directory-1-* should work.

As example, Google does - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt

Alternatively, you could setup htaccess / httpd.conf to return 403 if the URL starts with /directory-1- and the user agent contains the substring "bot".

Comment: If you are just blocking URLs that start `/directory-1-` then you don't need a "wildcard" at all and the trailing `*` should be removed (as per the Google doc you linked to). However, the question is arguably ambiguous (hence @Stephen's comment under the question)... whilst the examples appear to indicate URLs that start with `/directory-1-`, it's not actually what the question asks ("_including_ a given phrase") which is further enforced by the OP's code example that uses a "wildcard" at the start of the path value, ie. "`*/directory-1`".